# Slick 2.0 Map a java.util.Date in a Table

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I use slick 2.0 and I have a simple case class :

```
case class Message(id: Option[Long], userId: Option[Long], body:String, creationDate:Date)
```

And the following mapping :

```
class Messages(tag: Tag) extends Table[Message](tag, "message") {
  import Mapping.Mapper._

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def userId = column[Long]("user_id")
  def body = column[String]("body")
  def creationDate = column[java.util.Date]("creationDate")
  def * = (id.?, userId.?, body, creationDate) <> (Message.tupled, Message.unapply _)
}
```

I import this implicit mapper :

```
implicit def date2sqlDate(d: java.util.Date): java.sql.Date = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime())
```

I keep getting this error:

```
No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. 
Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
Required level: 
scala.slick.lifted.ShapeLevel.Flat Source type:
(scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Long]], 
scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Long]], 
scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], 
scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.sql.Date]) 
Unpacked type: (Option[Long], Option[Long], String, java.util.Date)
Packed type: Any
```

How can I use a java.util.Date in my table ? 
I don't want to use JodaTime or everything else, I want just plain old java.util.Date.

it looks like we need to use MappedColumnType 
http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/userdefined.html#scalar-types

but a simple mapping like this one doesn't work

```
implicit val date2sqlDateMapper = JdbcDriver.MappedJdbcType.base[java.util.Date, java.sql.Date](
      { d => date2sqlDate(d) }, 
      { sqlDate => sqlDate } 
      )
```

I'll get 
    could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.BaseColumnType[java.sql.Date]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  implicit val JavaUtilDateMapper =
    MappedColumnType .base[java.util.Date, java.sql.Timestamp] (
      d => new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime),
      d => new java.util.Date(d.getTime))
```

You need to have something like this in your implicit scope, **And as you have noticed, java.util.Date is mapped to java.sql.Timestamp, if you map to java.sql.Date, it will lose time part**